# Changing Text To Hyperlink In Java RCP Application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

My application is in Java RCP.
In the text area, I have a lot of paragraph text. I want to change one of the paragraph to hyperlink.

When I use this piece of code:

```
Link link = new Link (<parent composite>, SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK);
```

The hyperlink getting created is in a new pane under the parent composite window.

I want the text in the same composite window to change to hyperlink.

Any suggestions on what could be done on this ?

Comment: You can't _change_ it to be a link. You have to _create_ it as a link... BTW, what widget do you refer to as "paragraph text"?

Comment: With 'paragraph text', I meant text in different lines.
I want to convert one of the line to hyperlink of a local folder.
How do I do it ?

Comment: What _widget_? How do you do it? `text= new <What is here???>(parent, SWT.WHATEVER);` Please show the code you have, it is verz difficult to help blindfolded...

Comment: The code I am using is :

     Link link = new Link(parent, SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK);
     link.setText("<a href=\"www.google.com\">Google</a>");

Comment: Thanks, I'm not THAT dumb. I can read. I **did read that** in [your post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15545678/1667004). THE OTHER ONE PLEASE! The original. The first implementation. The one that has all the lots of lots of lines, paragraphs, and text in it. The one, that works, but you want to change it into a link. Please, anybody reading this: **am I that easy to misunderstand**?

Comment: Sorry for that.
Please let me know the code of how do you create a hyperlink in Java RCP.

Comment: I have 
Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3
in my text.. I want to create a hyperlink to the text: "Line 2".

How do I do that ?